# What is the purpose of readline().strip()?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, readline, strip

### **What is the purpose of readline().strip() (especially in the below code)?**

**Context:**

---

I was taking a look at the following code:

```
op = open('encyin.txt', 'r')
n, q = op.readline().split()
n = int(n)
q = int(q)
dic = {}

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    dic[str(i)]=(op.readline().strip())
```

And trying to interpret it.

---

**My Interpretation:**

---

The start is simple enough - it opens a file `encyin.txt` in read mode. It takes input - `n` & `p` - from the line, the `.split()` separating the two inputs. They are then classified as integers, and an empty list `dict` is created?

From there, a `for` loop is utilised.

**But what does the last line mean? I am not familiar with (a) `readline().strip()` and (b) how this affects list `dict` and the values of the input:**

---

> **For Example**

If `ency.txt` was the following:

```
6 5
1151
723
1321
815
780
931
```

---

What happens to the other numbers from the 2nd line downwards? Does the `readline().split` assign them a line number? Does it add it to the list `dict`, a bit like `.append`?

**What does the last line mean of the top code do? I am not familiar with (a) `readline().strip()` and (b) how this affects list `dict` and the values of the input:**

Answer (score 3):

In your text file, you have these things called whitespace characters. Often, these are spaces or enters ('\n') that you want to get rid of. The strip() helps you remove these whitespace characters.

If you were to print the numbers after reading them and without stripping, you would get:

```
number1

number2

number3

...
```

Because you haven't removed the hidden 'enter' character.

Comment: If you want to do something like (int(dic[1])), this would give an error because that line would also contain a \n

Comment: It's basically to remove any unneeded stuff in the code so that you can use the actual values.

Comment: So what does the dict[str(i)] do?

Comment: This helps assign the i key of the dictionary, to the number. Dictionaries are like lists, except rather than having indices, they have keys which can also be strings.

Comment: Oh so the dic is a dictionary, not a list?

Comment: Yes, this can be seen because it uses {} and not []

Comment: Could you explain what you mean - Dictionaries are like lists, except rather than having indices, they have keys which can also be strings

Comment: Imagine a list: l = [0, 2, 5, 6], the 0th element of this list l[0] is 0, the first element l[1] is 2, etc.

Comment: Ok. Consider the list imagined.

Comment: Now, imagine you wanted not to use numbers to access the elements of the list, rather you wanted to use strings: test_dic = {"number of chocolates": 5, etc.}

Comment: Then you could simply do test_dic["number of chocolates"] which would give you 5. https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp have a look at this

Comment: Ah, interesting. I see.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217363/discussion-between-bhavye-mathur-and-global05).

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at the source of this question (my original question)? And explain what I would do at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753367/assigning-a-input-on-a-line-to-its-line-number

Answer (score 3):

When reading a python script and you come across some function that you don't know, your goal should first to be understand the function out of context, and then you can figure out what they are doing in context.

The first port of call for understanding builtin/standard library functions  (as opposed to functions from some extra library) should be the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/). When the docs fail you, move on to other sources (there are plenty).

In this case, you want to know what `op.readline()` does. Well, what is `op`? I would go to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), and see that it creates a [`file object`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object), which tells you that the actual implementation used is in [`io`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#module-io). Here we can search the page for [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readline).

What do the docs have to say about `readline`?

> Read and return one line from the stream.

Here, I would assume, since it's a text file, "a line from the stream" is a string object (but you could always open a python interpreter to check), and look up [`string.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), which says:

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed. If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace.

Now put them together. They call `(op.readline().strip())`.

- We know `op` is a "file object" using `io`
- `io`'s readline reads a single line from the stream
- `some_string.strip()` called without parameters removes all whitespace from the start and end of `some_string`

Although python uses duck-typing, objects still have types/behaviours and understanding code often involves knowing what kind of object you are dealing with at any point so you can look into how it should work.

For example, if you know something is a `dictionary`, but you don't know what a [`dictionary`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) is, you should search the docs for some info and try to understand what it does out of context first.

Answer (score 2):

```
op = open('encyin.txt', 'r')
n, q = op.readline().split()
n = int(n)
q = int(q)
dic = {}

for i in range(1, n + 1):

 # Here you're creating a key-value pair using the str value of the loop variable
 # i as the dictionary key i.e. key dic[str(i)] creates the key, and the value is 
 # op.readline().strip(). strip() is a str method that removes trailing characters.
 # the default is to remove whitespace at the beginning and ends of the string. 
 # These spaces get trimmed off if the method is called

    dic[str(i)]=(op.readline().strip())
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str#str.strip

Answer (score 1):

`.readline()` reads a line from a file. The result includes a trailing `'\n'`.

`.strip()` removes all leading & trailing whitespace (e.g. the above-mentioned `'\n'`) from a string.

Thus, the last line of code `dic[str(i)]=(op.readline().strip())` does the following:

1. Reads line from the open file
2. Strips whitespace from the line
3. Stores the stripped line in the dictionary using the index (converted to string) as a key

Comment: I am not familiar with dictionaries, what does "key" mean?

Comment: @global05 A dictionary maps a set of keys to values. Keys are unique and this is how you access the stored values. E.g. in the above code `dic['5']` would return `'780'`.

For more see the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries.

I strongly suggest to do this if you want to understand python code.

Comment: @global05 research dictionaries??

Comment: Good idea - will do.

Comment: "removes all whitespace" - only at the beginning and end of the string

Answer (score 1):

readline() returning a single line as string from your file.

ex: for the given txt file info:

```
Danni Loss
Shani Amari
Michele favarotti
```

readline() will return the first line:

```
Danni Loss\n
```

then there is a use of strip() removes all empty chars from the start and end of the string, so you will get:

```
Danni Loss
```

Comment: The question is about `strip`, not `split`