# Unexpected space inserted by readline

Tags: python, readline

I'm facing an issue when I try to read and print lines from two files.
These files are similar but a space is always inserted in the second line printed.
Of course no one exists in my files.

```
file1 = open("compare1", "r")
file2 = open("compare2", "r")
while 1:
    line1 = file1.readline()
    line2 = file2.readline()
    if line1 == "" or line2 == "":
        break
    print(line1, line2)
file1.close()
file2.close()
```

The result is the following one :

> ```
> Salut je m'appelle Yohan
>  Salut je m'appelle Yohan
>
> Je suis très content
>  Je suis très content
> ```

Opening the file in a `with` block generates the same result.

The expected result is

> ```
> Salut je m'appelle Yohan
> Salut je m'appelle Yohan
>
> Je suis très content
> Je suis très content
> ```

Do you have an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each line within a text file implicitly ends with a newline (`\n`). When you are printing out `line1` and `line2`, it effectively becomes:

```
Salut je m'appelle Yohan\n Salut je m'appelle Yohan
```

Which outputs as

```
Salut je m'appelle Yohan
 Salut je m'appelle Yohan
```

To fix the problem just add `strip` to the end of your `readline` calls

```
    line1 = file1.readline().strip()
    line2 = file2.readline().strip()

    print(line1, line2, sep='\n')

    >>> Salut je m'appelle Yohan
    >>> Salut je m'appelle Yohan
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Done. The OP didn't really state how they wanted their output to look, so just gave a general answer

Comment: Since they took issue with the extra space on the second line, I assumed they wanted each on a separate line without a space, but you're right -- @Yohan, please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70218098/edit) your question to show your expected output

Comment: Not so implicit. The linefeed is *there*; it's just rendered by most text editors and other programs by moving the cursor to the beginning of the next line rather than displaying any particular glyph.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally found also this post which gives some other details : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772371/what-is-the-purpose-of-readline-strip)