# Creating folders in a directory using variables (os.path)

Tags: python, txt, os.path

I'm feeding my code lines from a txt file and using that to determine folder names.

```
import os


folderdir = r'C:\Users\myname\Documents\Folders'
txtfile = r'C:\Users\myname\Documents\foldernames.txt'

with open(txtfile) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        folderpath = folderdir + "\\" + line
        print(folderpath)
        os.makedirs(folderpath)
```

When I print the loop, I'm getting what looks like reasonable folder paths, ex.:

```
C:\Users\myname\Documents\Folders\Albert#2000555
```

Despite that I get this error:

```
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:\\Users\\myname\\Documents\\Folders\\Albert#2000555\n'
```

Comment: The lines being read from your file will end with a newline character - you need to use `.strip()` or some similar technique to get rid of it, before the result is a valid pathname.

Comment: As a general hint: if a string looks correct, but somehow isn't working, try printing the `repr()` of the string - various issues will become much more visible in that form.

Answer (score 0):

See the resulting path in the error-message `Albert#2000555\n`. It has a newline character `\n` at the end. This makes the path invalid to use.

As [commented by jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74117068/creating-folders-in-a-directory-using-variables-os-path/74117143#comment130860705_74117068):

- use [`repr(str)`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#repr) to print the actual representation
- use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove the newline at the end of the read lines:

```
import os

folderdir = r'C:\Users\myname\Documents\Folders'
txtfile = r'C:\Users\myname\Documents\foldernames.txt'

with open(txtfile) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        folderpath = folderdir + "\\" + line.strip()  # stripped to remove newline
        print(repr(folderpath))  # use repr() to visualize newlines
        os.makedirs(folderpath)
```

See also:

- [What is the purpose of readline().strip()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772371/what-is-the-purpose-of-readline-strip)
- [Handle line breaks (newlines) in Python | note.nkmk.me](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-string-line-break/)